# Properties of an arbitrary (i.e., not fitted) statistical model

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Suppose that I have a `data` and a statistical model that is not the result of fitting, but has a different origin. For example, I have a list of measurements and a theoretical model whose predicting accuracy I want to assess.

Is there a simple way to obtain all the properties of a `FittedModel` object, but from my theoretical model?

For example, suppose that

```
mt=Table[{i,1+i+RandomReal[]},{i,5}]
```

yields `mt={{1,2.56508},{2,3.58291},{3,4.8005},{4,5.24265},{5,6.38087}}`

If I call

```
LinearModelFit[mt,x,x]
```

I get

[image: FittedModel[1.72701 +0.929131 x]]

And I can then get R$^2$ for the adjusted model:

```
%["RSquared"]
```

which gives $0.9851$.

But I know the *theoretical* model is $1.5+x$. Can I have the power of a FittedModel (residuals, ANOVA, RSquared, etc.) for my non-fitted model?

Comment: If you look at `FullForm[LinearModelFit[mt,x,x]]` from your example above then the internal structure seems reasonably simple and understandable. What happens if you carefully build a `FittedModel` using that structure as an example, not by doing a fit but by substituting your theoretical model in that and then you query that constructed `FittedModel` for residuals, ANOVA, etc? Can you do this on test cases where you know what the calculations should show to verify that this is being done correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `NonlinearModelFit` but not all output options will either be appropriate and some will require "adjustment".

All of the fitting procedures want to estimate parameters (that's what they're made for) so `NonlinearModelFit` can be tricked by included a parameter that isn't in the model.  Here I used a parameter named `a`:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
mt = Table[{i, 1 + i + RandomReal[]}, {i, 5}]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mt, 1.5 + x, {a}, x]
```

So the following work fine with no adjustment needed:

```
nlm["FitResiduals"]
(* {-0.378754, -0.170078, 0.282753, -0.0698316, -0.276414} *)
nlm["PredictedResponse"]
(* {2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5} *)
```

The "EstimatedVariance" needs adjustment:

```
Mean[(mt[[All, 2]] - 1.5 - mt[[All, 1]])^2]
(* 0.0667223 *)
n = Length[mt];
nlm["EstimatedVariance"] (n - 1)/n
(* 0.0667223 *)
```

Comment: Nice! You get some information on the _dummy_ model/parameter `a` (in the ANOVA, ParameterTable, etc.), is it possible to get such information for my coefficients (i.e., 1.5 and 1)? Or is all that kind of information just meaningless for a non-fitted model?

Comment: Yes, I'd vote for meaningless.  I'd also avoid any option that starts with `"Parameter..."` as the residual variance is the only parameter estimated.