# LinearModelFit with predefined coefficients

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I want to use an estimation procedure different from OLS (say, LAR or LASSO), but then use the LinearModelFit to produce all the diagnostic statistics.

Can I make LinearModelFit or the FittedModel to accept my set of estimated coefficients and produce the diagnostic statistics?

Comment: ‘NonlinearModelFit’ should give you the desired flexibility and all of the same diagnostics.

Comment: To use `LinearModelFit` with known coefficients just subtract the contribution (known coefficient * predictor value) from the response variable and use that as the response variable with the associated predictors removed.

Comment: also here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188290/properties-of-an-arbitrary-i-e-not-fitted-statistical-model?rq=1